# Spring Security deprecated issue, rewrite old bean

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, deprecated

I'm trying to upgrade to Spring Boot 3.0.0 and Spring Security 6.0.
I've found that method for securing requests `authorizeRequests()` has been deprecated. And also method `csrf()` and `exceptionHandling()` has been deprecated. How can I upgrade my security configuration?

My code:

```
 @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain securityWebFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http, AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
        return http
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeExchange()
                .pathMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS)
                .permitAll()
                .pathMatchers(publicRoutes)
                .permitAll()
                .anyExchange()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint((swe , e) -> {
                    log.error("IN securityWebFilterChain - unauthorized error: {}", e.getMessage());
                    return Mono.fromRunnable(() -> swe.getResponse().setStatusCode(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED));
                })
                .accessDeniedHandler((swe, e) -> {
                    log.error("IN securityWebFilterChain - access denied: {}", e.getMessage());

                    return Mono.fromRunnable(() -> swe.getResponse().setStatusCode(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN));
                })
                .and()
                .addFilterAt(bearerAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager), SecurityWebFiltersOrder.AUTHENTICATION)
                .build();
    }
```

In docs.spring.io it is recommended to use a lambda-based configuration instead. Please help rewrite the method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Goals of the Lambda DSL**

> ```
> Automatic indentation makes the configuration more readable.
>
> The is no need to chain configuration options using .and()
>
> The Spring Security DSL has a similar configuration style to other Spring DSLs such as Spring Integration and Spring Cloud Gateway.
> ```

Your `securityWebFilterChain` will have next one body based on lambda DSL:

```
  @Bean
  public SecurityWebFilterChain securityWebFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http,
      AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
     http.csrf(CsrfSpec::disable);
     http.authorizeExchange(authorizeExchangeSpec ->
             authorizeExchangeSpec.pathMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS).permitAll()
                 .pathMatchers(publicRoutes).permitAll()
                 .anyExchange().authenticated());
    http.exceptionHandling(exceptionHandlingSpec -> {
          exceptionHandlingSpec.authenticationEntryPoint((swe , e) -> {
            log.error("IN securityWebFilterChain - unauthorized error: {}", e.getMessage());
            return Mono.fromRunnable(() -> swe.getResponse().setStatusCode(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED));
          })
              .accessDeniedHandler((swe, e) -> {
                log.error("IN securityWebFilterChain - access denied: {}", e.getMessage());

                return Mono.fromRunnable(() -> swe.getResponse().setStatusCode(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN));
              });
        });

    http.addFilterAt(bearerAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager), SecurityWebFiltersOrder.AUTHENTICATION);
    return http.build();
  }
```

Also you should read next one documentation resources:

[Migration Reactive](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/migration/reactive.html)

Here you will have more about  [`Use the Lambda DSL`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/migration-7/configuration.html)